# Reading a raw binary data in python and converting it into ascii

Tags: python, python-2.7, binaryfiles, binary-data

I have a raw binary data and I want to convert it into a readable text.

the text contains with something that is not readable, it has also special characters, like black box with NUL word or " N–[«´N–[«  )›  )ÿ " . I'm just new in python.

here's my code

```
import struct
file = open('rawbinary.txt')
text = file.read()
struct.unpack("iiiii", text[:20])
```

my output was:

```
(2113933569, 67305475, -80477197, 1536577129, 1312228259)
```

and if add this:

```
text[:10]
```

my output is

```
'\x01\x11\x00~\x03\x00\x03\x04\xf3\x03'
```

Am I doing it right? What is my next step?

Comment: what's your OS, you should open the file with `'rb'` on windows (linux does not need the binary differentiation).

Comment: can you gist/fiddle/pastebin...etc your rawbinary.txt file, what do you expect to see?  your format string is `'iiii'` which means format as integer. http://docs.python.org/2/library/struct.html (also, change to open('rawbinary.txt', 'rb') for consistent behavior on windows)

Comment: i want to see it in ascii form.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use the built-in [ord](http://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#ord) function.

```
with open("/bin/ls", "rb") as fin:
  buf = fin.read()
bytes = map(ord, buf)    
print bytes[:10]
```

output:

```
[127, 69, 76, 70, 2, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0]
```

Comment: can this be outputted into ascii?

Comment: i mean. into letters.

Comment: No. Some of the byte codes (e.g. anything less than 65) correspond to symbols that are not letters.